# What is TextAffinity in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, text-rendering

The TextAffinity enum in Flutter has the following [documentation description](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/TextAffinity-class.html):

> A way to disambiguate a TextPosition when its offset could match two
> different locations in the rendered string.
>
> For example, at an offset where the rendered text wraps, there are two
> visual positions that the offset could represent: one prior to the
> line break (at the end of the first line) and one after the line break
> (at the start of the second line). A text affinity disambiguates
> between these two cases.
>
> This affects only line breaks caused by wrapping, not explicit newline
> characters. For newline characters, the position is fully specified by
> the offset alone, and there is no ambiguity.
>
> TextAffinity also affects bidirectional text at the interface between
> LTR and RTL text. Consider the following string, where the lowercase
> letters will be displayed as LTR and the uppercase letters RTL:
> "helloHELLO". When rendered, the string would appear visually as
> "helloOLLEH". An offset of 5 would be ambiguous without a
> corresponding TextAffinity. Looking at the string in code, the offset
> represents the position just after the "o" and just before the "H".
> When rendered, this offset could be either in the middle of the string
> to the right of the "o" or at the end of the string to the right of
> the "H".

This kind of makes sense but it's still a little confusing. For example "helloHELLO" isn't actually bidirectional text. How is offset 5 ambiguous? Do you have a visual example?

*I'm adding my answer below.*

Answer (score 1):

TextAffinity disambiguates text position for soft wraps and bidirectional text boundaries. The affinity can be either upstream or downstream. Downstream is the default.

## Soft wrap position

Given the string `0123456789` whose last character soft-wraps to the next line, you can choose the cursor position as follows. Both positions are at offset `9`:

#### Downstream

[image]

#### Upstream

[image]

## Bidirectional text boundary

Given the string `Helloשלום` where `Hello` is LRT text and `שלום` is RTL text, you can choose the cursor position at the boundary between them as follows. Both positions are at offset `5`:

#### Downstream

[image]

#### Upstream

[image]

## Going on

I write about this in more detail [here](https://suragch.medium.com/a-visual-guide-to-text-affinity-in-flutter-94ef3ea98794).